# Creating a report from features that have been selected

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-9.3, vba

I'm in need of some guidance,
I have created an application where the users does the following workflow

1. Enter Postcode
2. Zoom to Postcode
3. Create a buffer at specified distance
4. Spatial Query to find points within the buffer
5. MsgBox appears with the Organisation Name that are within the buffer.
6. Create report with the Organisation details.

Number 6 is what I need help on, I want to create a pdf report with details from the attribute table, and a map of the buffer and points,  any ideas on what are my options/examples of using Arcobjects in creating reports that look good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need ArcObjects per se to export to pdf. You can use a external library to print to pdf, such as [itext](http://www.ujihara.jp/iTextdotNET/en/).

Use ArcObjects (you already have your IRows or IFeatures) to work with the data and massage it into a report and use iText to spit that pdf out.

Answer (score 0):

[You commented](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22924/creating-a-report-from-features-that-have-been-selected#comment31387_22939) that you may be investigating ReportLab to write your reports, presumably with Python.  I have done it that way in the past.

When next I try to do this from Python I may try these ArcPy techniques:

- [ExportReport function](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/reports/exportreport.htm) (ArcMap):

> The ExportReport function provides a mechanism to automate the
>   generation of reports using layers or tables authored in a map
>   document (.mxd) or layers in a layer file (.lyr). A report layout file
>   authored in ArcMap is a template that stores information about the
>   content and placement of the items in a report. The report layout file
>   is used along with the source data in a map document to create output
>   reports. The source data can also have associated joins and related
>   table information that is used within the report.

- [Report class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/report-class.htm) (ArcGIS Pro)

> The Report object references a report in an ArcGIS Pro project (.aprx)
>   file. It provides access to common properties such as definition query
>   and export.